# Define a Typescript string type of comma separated union types?

Tags: typescript

How do you create a Typescript string type, which includes values from a union type ***AND*** is separated by commas?

I think this doesn't exist, but I'm asking anyway...

```
type AcceptableVal = 'cool' | 'wow' | 'biz' | 'sweet' | 'yowza' | 'fantastic';
type Amaze = // how do you define this?;

const dabes: Amaze = 'cool,wow';
const fancy: Amaze = 'biz,wow,fantastic';
const hachiMachi: Amaze = 'yowza,biz,sweet';
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Typescript 4.3.4 Update

You can now use [string template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to define a pattern like:

```
type S = 'cool' | 'wow' | 'biz' | 'sweet' | 'yowza' | 'fantastic';
type Test = `${S},${S}`
```

What you still can't do is make this infinitely extensible, like an array. To make this work typescript generates every single combination as a union. But for small lists like this it can work.

For example:

```
type S = 'cool' | 'wow' | 'biz' | 'sweet' | 'yowza' | 'fantastic';
type Amaze =
    | `${S}`
    | `${S},${S}`
    | `${S},${S},${S}`
    | `${S},${S},${S},${S}`
    | `${S},${S},${S},${S},${S}`
    | `${S},${S},${S},${S},${S},${S}`
```

If you hover over `Amaze`, you will see the type reported as:

```
type Amaze = S | "cool,cool" | "cool,wow" | "cool,biz" | "cool,sweet" 
| "cool,yowza" | "cool,fantastic" | "wow,cool" | "wow,wow"
| "wow,biz" | "wow,sweet" | "wow,yowza" | "wow,fantastic"
| ... 55967 more ...| "fantastic,fantastic,fantastic,fantastic,fantastic,fantastic"
```

[See typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAylC8UDkBjA9mgNkqAfZA7mgTvkgEYCWAXqcgM4EQTB1IjHUCGbAZlwDtgXesEookAbgBQoSFACCAWy7Vo8aVC14oAAwAkAbxgBfXZu34DxkwBojp89p3XT9m+8cWtVh3b+e-jZOlnoB4R4RXs6+kXFuUUFe0ugColAAJlzkEPQAXIoqagjI6Fi2RCQyqen8AiggBcqq6shU1BXEtnXCouJSKWhpwFAAFlwoo5QAshNTTUWt7Jxctu22jMysMoPDUORcGTDAAE6UAgDmCy0lSLwYa1wnOAD0L1By0BAnJ2gnQA)

Notice that `... 55967 more ...`. Amaze is now a union with over *fifty five thousand* possible values. This may affect performance in your IDE at this point. And if you add the version that takes 7 strings you'll get a type error:

```
Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.(2590)
```

Eventually typescript cuts you off for performance sake. But again, for small lists, this may be viable.

---

## Original answer: Typescript 3.7

You can't.

Typescript can type `string`s which can have any content, or can it can type exact strings like `"cool"` or `"wow"`. But typescript will never know about if a string contains certain characters.

The only way to make this work would be to store these as an array instead:

```
type AmazeArray = AcceptableVal[];
const dabes: AmazeArray = ['cool', 'wow'];
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. I want to type a function argument that's passed to a  query param... Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 9):

with new template string feature of ts4.1 you can do this using following utils

```js
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void
    ? I
    : never;
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never>;

type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;

type UnionConcat<U extends string, Sep extends string> = PopUnion<U> extends infer SELF
    ? SELF extends string
        ? Exclude<U, SELF> extends never
            ? SELF
            :
                  | `${UnionConcat<Exclude<U, SELF>, Sep>}${Sep}${SELF}`
                  | UnionConcat<Exclude<U, SELF>, Sep>
                  | SELF
        : never
    : never;
```

example

```
type Keys = "a" | "b" | "c";
type Test = UnionConcat<Keys, ",">
// Test = "a" | "b" | "c" | "a,b" | "a,c" | "b,c" | "a,b,c"


type Test2 = UnionConcat<Keys, "-">
// Test2 = "a" | "b" | "c" | "a-b" | "a-c" | "b-c" | "a-b-c"
```

Comment: Could you show how this is used with the example from the OP please?

Comment: This definitely looks promising but `UnionConcat<'red' | 'blue' | 'orange', 'mouse' | 'dog'>` is equal to `"red" | "blue" | "orange" | "red,mouse,blue" | "red,dog,blue" | "red,mouse,orange" | "red,dog,orange" | "blue,mouse,orange" | "blue,dog,orange" | "red,mouse,blue,mouse,orange" | "red,mouse,blue,dog,orange" | "red,dog,blue,mouse,orange" | "red,dog,blue,dog,orange"` and I really have no idea what that's supposed to mean!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver You can appropriate this to a comma separated string list, for example: `type StringList = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'` and passing it to `UnionConcat` eg: `UnionConcat<StringList, ','>` would return a unique commas separated list with all the values,  eg: `'"foo" | "bar" | "baz" | "foo,bar" | "foo,baz" | "bar,baz" | "foo,bar,baz"`. It's actually rather elegant. Thanks @MHA15 for this.

Comment: @User_coder yes it's definitely cool - I just wish he'd added an example or explanation. I mean if he was in a hurry I'd rather him just post this than not post it, but I didn't realize what 'Sep' meant (yes it's obvious with your example).

Comment: Nice thing about this is you can actually define a type `type FooBarBazCombinations = UnionConcat<StringList, ','>` and then you get autocomplete when you type `const combination: FooBarBazCombinations = "..."`. Unfortunately you can only enter combinations in the order they are originally defined but that's probably a good thing!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver 100% agree, should we add an additional answer to this question and include more information?

Comment: @User_coder I think it's fair to add an example or two to the end of this answer for usage. Unless you have a separate version that allows keys in different orders. I attempted to do that before I found this answer and didn't quite crack it! I tried to 'exclude' the values you'd used so far but I didn't manage to complete it.

Comment: thanks to your responses, just added some examples for you

Comment: @MHA15 Is there a way to update this to include `"b-a" | "b-c" | etc`?

Comment: That's wicked! We can remove the lines `| UnionConcat<Exclude<U, SELF>, Sep>` and `| SELF` so that we rule out `"a" | "b" | "c"` and return only concatenated unions, as in `Test1 = "a,b" | "a,c" | "b,c" | "a,b,c"`. Genius! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of do this with [template literal types.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)

```
type GoodDog = 'ruger' | 'kim' | 'abbie' | 'bo' | 'jasper';

type DogList = `${ GoodDog }` | 
               `${ GoodDog },${ GoodDog }` | 
               `${ GoodDog },${ GoodDog },${ GoodDog }`;

const favoriteDogs1: DogList = 'kim,abbie,ruger'
```

This would support dog lists up to 3, and allow duplicates. You could add more as needed.

Unfortunately if you try to make this recursive it won't allow it. I think theoretically it may be possible to make a type that would be recursive with a 'tail condition' but I couldn't immediately figure it out.

A better way may be to use `as const` on an array (NOT a type).

```
 const Colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange'] as const;
```

This is a runtime variable array, so you can display it in your UI - add it to a dropdown etc.

Then you need to extract the 'type' of this constant array (which is only possible because we made it const).

```
type ExtractArrayType<T> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer U> ? U : never;

type ColorType = ExtractArrayType<typeof Colors>;
```

This will give us:

```
ColorType = 'red' | 'blue' | 'green' | 'orange;
```

Note that if we hadn't defined the original array with `as const` then `ColorType` would just be `string`.

We can now use this type and create an array;

```
const colorList: ColorType[] = ['red', 'blue'];
```

This approach is more useful for most runtime cases, although occasionally it would be nice to define something like `red,blue` and have that type checked.